Pdf is available in console but unable to see network tab
import { axiosInstances } from "./axiosInstanc"
interface upladPdfPayload {
    name: string;
    pdf: File
}
export const uploadPdfApi = async (payload: upladPdfPayload) => {
    try {
        console.log(payload);
        const res = await axiosInstances.post('/pdf/upload', payload);
        return res.data;
    } catch (error: any) {
        return error.response.data;
    }
}

value in console
name: 'Resarch paper certificate.pdf', pdf: File}
name: "Resarch paper certificate.pdf"
pdf: File
lastModified: 1713083292691
lastModifiedDate: Sun Apr 14 2024 13:58:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
name: "Resarch paper certificate.pdf"
size: 937460
type: "application/pdf"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
[[Prototype]]: Object
axiosInstance
import axios from "axios";
import { baseUrl } from "./baseUrl";

function getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("token");
}

export const axiosInstances = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseUrl,
    headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}`
    }
})

axiosInstances.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${getToken()}`;
    return config;
});

I try everytning check console and network tabe , but unable to solve it , i want to see pdf in network tab in payload

To make PDF available in the network tab you need to format it properly in  multipart/form-data
Modify the uploadPdfApi function to use FormData:
export const uploadPdfApi = async (payload: UploadPdfPayload) => {
try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', payload.name);
    formData.append('pdf', payload.pdf);

    const res = await axiosInstances.post('/pdf/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
    });

    return res.data;

} catch (error: any) {
        return error.response.data;
    }
};

